# Kafka to Kafka -> reading source kafka topic multiple times

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I new to Kafka and i have a configuration where i have a source Kafka topic which has messages with a default retention for 7 days. I have 3 brokers with 1 partition and 1 replication.

When i try to consume messages from source Kafka topic and to my target Kafka topic i was able to consume messages in the same order. Now my question is if i am trying to reprocess all the messages from my source Kafka and consume in ,y Target Kafka i see that my Target Kafka is not consuming any messages. I know that duplication should be avoided but lets say i have a scenario where i have 100 messages in my source Kafka and i am expecting 200 messages in my target Kafka after running it twice. But i am just getting 100 messages in my first run and my second run returns nothing.

Can some one please explain why this is happening and what is the functionality behind it ?

Comment: Please, provide a better explanation, and some demonstration of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka consumer reads data from a partition of a topic. One consumer can read from one partition at one time only.

Once a message has been read by the consumer, it can't be re-read again. Let me first explain the current offset. When we call a poll method, Kafka sends some messages to us. Let us assume we have 100 records in the partition. The initial position of the current offset is 0. We made our first call and received 100 messages. Now Kafka will move the current offset to 100.

The current offset is a pointer to the last record that Kafka has already sent to a consumer in the most recent poll and that has been committed. So, the consumer doesn't get the same record twice because of the current offset. Please go through the following diagram and URL for complete understanding.
https://www.learningjournal.guru/courses/kafka/kafka-foundation-training/offset-management/

[image]